# CallLogs in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, calllog

i am working on CallLogs Sync Application in Blackberry and partially i have done it, one point that i didn't understand is how to add information to CallLogs. I have retrieved information from CallLogs and Store on Server but now i retrieved information from Server but how to add info to CallLogs didn't come in my mind as i retrieved all the information in Strings from Server and PhoneCallLog Constructor look like this:

PhoneCallLog call = new PhoneCallLog(Date,int Type,int Duration,int Status,participantID participant,String Notes);

Please tell me as soon as Possible, i will be very thankful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

class `net.rim.blackberry.api.phone.phonelogs.PhoneLogs` has method `addCall(CallLog call)` that adds a log item.

create `PhoneCallLog` instance with the constructor you posted and add it to `PhoneLogs`. You need to have the app signed to use these methods.  (see  http://www.blackberry.com/go/codesigning )

API documentation:
http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/6022/net/rim/blackberry/api/phone/phonelogs/PhoneLogs.html

http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/6022/net/rim/blackberry/api/phone/phonelogs/PhoneCallLog.html